# FileSystemWatcher Not Working with UNC Paths. Wrong Implementation or Alternatives to FileSystemWatcher?

Tags: c#, filesystemwatcher

Hi I created a service to monitor several UNC paths. The goal of the watcher is to monitor several folders. When a new file is created it will trigger a launch of a file converter for that specific file. The file converter is a different .net console application exe. I am using the following code excerpt in the service:

```
static List<String> filesInProgress = new List<string>();
static List<FileSystemWatcher> listOfWatchers = new List<FileSystemWatcher>();

protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
{

    UserSettingsUtil.InitServiceSettings();
    _applicationExeDir = UserSettingsUtil.TDX2KlarfExePath;
    _tdx2KlarfExeName = UserSettingsUtil.TDX2KlarfApplicationExeName;
    _foldersToWatch = UserSettingsUtil.FoldersWatched;
    Watch();
}
```

My watcher logic:

```
private static void Watch()
{
    string[] paths = _foldersToWatch.Split(',');
    foreach (string dir in paths)
    {
        string dirTrim = dir.Trim();
        if (Directory.Exists(dirTrim))
        {
            FileSystemWatcher fileWatcher = new FileSystemWatcher();
            fileWatcher.Path = dirTrim;
            fileWatcher.Created += File_Created;
            //fileWatcher.Changed += OnChanged;
            fileWatcher.Filter = "*.gz";
            fileWatcher.IncludeSubdirectories = true;
            fileWatcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
            Logger.Info($"Started service monitoring {dirTrim}");
            listOfWatchers.Add(fileWatcher);
        }
    }
}

private static void File_Created(object sender, FileSystemEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.ChangeType == WatcherChangeTypes.Created)
    {
        if (Directory.Exists(e.FullPath))
        {
            foreach (string file in Directory.GetFiles(e.FullPath))
            {
                var eventArgs = new FileSystemEventArgs(
                    WatcherChangeTypes.Created,
                    Path.GetDirectoryName(file),
                    Path.GetFileName(file));
                //Logger.Info($"Inner Loop file create {file}");
                File_Created(sender, eventArgs);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            var fullFilePath = e.FullPath;
            Logger.Info("{0} created.", fullFilePath);
            if (!filesInProgress.Contains(fullFilePath))
            {
                Thread converter = new Thread(ConfigureAndStartProcess);
                converter.Start(fullFilePath);
                filesInProgress.Add(fullFilePath);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then on stop:

```
protected override void OnStop()
{
    //watcher.Dispose();
    if (listOfWatchers.Count > 0)
    {
        foreach (var dirWatcher in listOfWatchers)
        {
            dirWatcher.Dispose();
        }
    }
}
```

However this logic only works for local directories. I have looked through S/O questions and it appears that FileSystemWatcher is not reliable and has several issues including with UNC paths.

Given what I am trying to achieve, can someone help me come up with an alternative example to FileSystemWatcher that can achive what I am looking for several directories? Or is there something wrong with the way I am using FileSystemWatcher?

The UNC paths look like this: \tooltypedir.companyname.com\somedir\topfolder\toolvariant\data_ready\

Comment: As always, the way to go about something is to either write it yourself, or find someone else who's done it and reuse what they've done. Stack Overflow isn't here implement a solution for you, nor is it here to locate libraries for you. You'll either need to go attempt to implement this, or find a 3rd party library through your own research. If you get stuck writing your own implementation or consuming a 3rd party library you've found, then Stack Overflow can be of use: you'd provide a [mcve] and clearly explain what you're doing and what's not working about it.

Comment: I modified the question. So I posted the code and clarified in my edit that if something is wrong with my implementation if it can be shown. And if not, what alternatives there might be @mason

Comment: The alternatives are as I already mentioned: write your own FileWatcher implementation or find an alternative that does what you want. Or re-plan the strategy: must you use FileWatcher? Is it not enough to code something to poll the directory periodically?

Comment: I came across this issue about 10 years ago. At the time I ended up writing my own implementation of FileWatcher based on polling the directory periodically to detect changes - the only reliable way to do it with UNC folders. Even for local folders the FileWatcher would occasionally drop file creation events.

Comment: @NickGoloborodko Thanks for the feedback. I thought I was doing something wrong with my implementation but it looks like this is a known issue. Looks like I will need to draft a polling way from scratch.